# How to get Smarty Template Highlighting in Zend Studio 9?

Tags: macos, smarty, zend-studio

I am trying to find a way to get smarty templates, `.tpl` files, to work with Zend Studio 9. The smartypdt plugin fails to install on Mac OS, and all the other `File Associations`--I have tried PHP Editor and HTML as associated editor--fail, too. This time stating: "Unsupported content type in editor". So all I am left with is a plain text mode.

How do I get basic template highlighting? I do not necessarily want smarty support anymore, just basic HTML and JavaScript highlighting would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `File Associations` Panel, there is a link to `Content Types`. There, I have added `*.tpl` file to the `HTML` view node. This ensures basic html highlighting and goes a long way when compared to the *plain* text mode.

Comment: To the poor soul who has upvoted me right now: Get phpstorm or some other IDE that actually allows you to do your job.